# How to pass array of sql query to function

Tags: java, jdbc

What's wrong in code.
Please help me on this.
How do I pass array of query to function exeSearchQuery();

```
  public class  MyDBConnect
    {
    Connection dbCon = null;
        public String DB_USERNAME = "root";
        public String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
        private String DB_DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        private String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/yatin";
    public  boolean connectToDb( ) throws Exception{
        try{
    Class.forName (DB_DRIVER_CLASS);
            dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
            //dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(tns, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in DBConnect "+e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList exeSearchQuery(String sql[]) throws Exception{

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList  data = null;
        int recordSize=0;
            try{

                connectToDb( );
                stmt = dbCon.createStatement( );
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int numOfCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();

                data = new ArrayList( );
                String q="";
                for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
                {
                    boolean chkQuery=true;
                    q=sql[k];
                    while(rs.next()){
                    chkQuery=true;
                    recordSize=recordSize+1;
                    String row[] = new String[numOfCols];
                    for(int col=1;col<=numOfCols ;col++)
                    {
                        row[col-1] = rs.getString(col);
                    }
                    data.add(row);
                    }
                    System.out.println("data="+data);

                    if(chkQuery=true)
                        {
                        break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            q=sql[1];
                            while(rs.next())
                            {
                                chkQuery=true;
                                recordSize=recordSize+1;
                                String row[] = new String[numOfCols];
                                for(int col=1;col<=numOfCols ;col++)
                                {
                                    row[col-1] = rs.getString(col);
                                }
                                data.add(row);
                                System.out.println("data="+data);
                            }
                        }
                        if(chkQuery=true)
                        {
                        break;
                        }
                    }

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error in DBConnect "+e);
            }finally{
                if(rs !=null) rs.close();
                if(stmt !=null)stmt.close();
                if(dbCon !=null) dbCon.close();
            }
        return data;
        //return recordSize;
    }

        public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception{
            MyDBConnect db = new MyDBConnect( );
            //db.connectToDb();
                            System.out.println("Connected");
            String query[] ={"select a.ID,a.VDT,a.AID,a.NAME,a.ADD,a.CONTACT,a.PTM,a.DEPT_TEXT,a.FLOOR,b.LINK from tm_co123 a LEFT JOIN tm_co456 b ON a.ID=b.PID where a.NAME like 'anil' ORDER BY ID","select a.ID,a.VDT,a.AID,a.NAME,a.ADD,a.CONTACT,a.PTM,a.DEPT_TEXT,b.LINK from tm_co123 a LEFT JOIN tm_co456 b ON a.ID=b.PID where a.ADD like 'anil' ORDER BY ID"};       
            db.exeSearchQuery(query[]);
        }
    }
```

If I run above code I am getting Error as

```
MyDBConnect.java:473: '.class' expected
                db.exeSearchQuery(query[]);
                                         ^
1 error
```

If I replaces query[] with query then it givs me Error as

```
MyDBConnect.java:406: executeQuery(java.lang.String) in java.sql.Statement canno
t be applied to (java.lang.String[])
                        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                                 ^
Note: MyDBConnect.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  passed it as `executeSearchQuery(query)` as I defined it as `String query[]={}`
and it worked and I got desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a `String[]` to [`executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29), it expects a single `String` as an argument. Either execute each query separately, or turn them into one using perhaps `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass array, to the `executeQuery();` method only you can pass string eg-`executeQuery(sql[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Even if your code is not the best that you can do, your `sql` is an array and not a `String`. And array can't be passed to `executeQuery`.

Here's a quick edit of your method :

```
        ...
            connectToDb( );
            for(String str : sql){ //This way you're doing each query of your array
                stmt = dbCon.createStatement( );
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int numOfCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                data = new ArrayList( );
                String q="";
                for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
                    boolean chkQuery=true;
                    q=sql[k];
                    while(rs.next()){
                        chkQuery=true;
                        recordSize=recordSize+1;
                        String row[] = new String[numOfCols];
                        for(int col=1;col<=numOfCols ;col++){
                            row[col-1] = rs.getString(col);
                        }
                    data.add(row);
                }
            }
        ...
```

Comment: But this foreach loop doesn't support in lower version of tomcat say Tomcat 4.

Answer (score 1):

`stmt.executeQuery()` method only accepts `String` parameter.

1. In your main(), call `db.exeSearchQuery()` method, it accepts parameter `String[]`.
   But for writing like `exeSearchQuery(query[])`, `query` is already 1D array.
   it is first mistake.
2. In your `exeSearchQuery(String sql[])` method, 
   `stmt.executeQuery()` requires `String` parameter. Writing like this `stmt.executeQuery(sql)`. Since now `sql` is 1D array. It is second mistake.

I try like this,
in exeSearchQuery(String sql[]) method

```
Edit rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql[0]);
```

in main() method,

```
String[] query = {.........};
db.exeSearchQuery(query);// edited
```

It connects to db.

Answer (score 0):

`executeQuery` accept  `String` not `String[]`do something like below.

```
List<ResultSet> lList=new ArrayList<ResultSet>();
for(String query :sql){
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            lList.add(rs);
        }
```